# 'Expected a type' error when declaring CGPoint parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to declare a function like so in my .h file:

```
- (NSDictionary *) dictionaryForNextTutorialStepFromPoint: (CGPoint) fromPoint;
```

And I'm getting the error `Expected a type`. Why would this be?

[image]

Also note I have imported Core Foundation:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Here is the entire file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface KDTutorialManager : NSObject

+ (KDTutorialManager *) sharedManager;

- (void) startTutorialForType: (int) momentType;
- (NSDictionary *) dictionaryForNextTutorialStepFromPoint: (CGPoint) fromPoint;
```

Comment: try importing CoreFoundation #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

Comment: @Dare I have imported core foundation

Comment: Are you inheriting properly? The only way I was able to reproduce this error was by failing to inherit from NSObject.

Comment: may be you are misising a semicolon somewhere in the .h file. Xcode points to wrong location if you end a line without statemetn.

Comment: If that's really the entire file you've posted, then you're missing the `@end`

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the Core Graphics headers to get the declaration of `CGPoint`. You can do so directly `#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>`, or by including the Cocoa Touch headers: `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`.

Foundation doesn't include Core Graphics.

(Also, note that you've imported Foundation, not Core Foundation: they are not the same thing, although the former does include the latter.)

Comment: Is this a new thing? Foundation used to include CoreGraphics, right?